# Most efficient way to get the world position of the 8 vertices of a Box Collider

Tags: unity, c#, transformation, linear-algebra, collider

What I am looking for is the most efficient way to get the world position of the 8 vertices of the Box Collider of a freely rotated Game Object. I cannot use collider.bounds since object is rotated, not axis-aligned.

I'm using Unity 5 with C#.

Comment: Typically you make a matrix out of all the matrices that transform the game object (hierarchically), and you multiply the vertex by that matrix... Your question is quite vague.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will try to figure out what you've said... As for my question, I don't get why it is that vague: I thought it was a very specific question to ask how to find out the world position of the 8 external vertexes of a Box Collider (my mention to a rotated Gameobject was only to prevent from receiving suggestions of using collider.bounds)

Comment: Given the tags and the text, it's hard to understand you use a framework; we only know you use c# and have a box collider, without actually knowing your implementation. Are you using Unity? This would be a very important tag to add to your question. Although this Q&A site welcomes a lot of Unity questions (and answers), this is not a Unity _only_ stack (Unity or any other framework), so we can't assume anything about the base technology you use. This is why I said your question is vague. You should edit your question (and tags) to give a bit more details, I'm sure you'll get better answers :)

Comment: Oh, now I see what you mean. Sorry for not providing such information beforehand. I thought that for this question there would be no difference between frameworks, provided that they employ C# and PhysX. But even though, I did not mention PhysX either. So I will edit it! Many thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
    BoxCollider b = obj.GetComponent<BoxCollider>(); //retrieves the Box Collider of the GameObject called obj

    Vector3 vertice1 = myobject.transform.TransformPoint(b.center + new Vector3(-b.size.x, -b.size.y, -b.size.z)*0.5f);
    Vector3 vertice2 = myobject.transform.TransformPoint(b.center + new Vector3(b.size.x, -b.size.y, -b.size.z)*0.5f);
    Vector3 vertice3 = myobject.transform.TransformPoint(b.center + new Vector3(b.size.x, -b.size.y, b.size.z)*0.5f);
    Vector3 vertice4 = myobject.transform.TransformPoint(b.center + new Vector3(-b.size.x, -b.size.y, b.size.z)*0.5f);
    Vector3 vertice5 = myobject.transform.TransformPoint(b.center + new Vector3(-b.size.x, b.size.y, -b.size.z)*0.5f);
    Vector3 vertice6 = myobject.transform.TransformPoint(b.center + new Vector3(b.size.x, b.size.y, -b.size.z)*0.5f);
    Vector3 vertice7 = myobject.transform.TransformPoint(b.center + new Vector3(b.size.x, b.size.y, b.size.z)*0.5f);
    Vector3 vertice8 = myobject.transform.TransformPoint(b.center + new Vector3(-b.size.x, b.size.y, b.size.z)*0.5f);
```

Comment: I know this is late, but that looks very repetitive, I'd suggest moving it into an array.

Comment: Can someone improve this answer explaining how this accounts for any rotation of the box? I don't see any orientation information being accounted for here. I'm guessing "size" on the collider has directional context since it's a Vector3, but confirmation from someone with more experience in Unity would be reassuring.

Comment: @ScottLin the `TransformPoint` function applies the orientation, translation, and scale of the object's transform (and its parent transforms) to the input point.

Answer (score 2):

If you can access a Mesh of the same size and shape, you can use [Mesh.bounds](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-bounds.html), which returns positions in local space.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<Vector3> GetBoxColliderCornersWorld(BoxCollider boxCollider)
{
    Vector3 size = boxCollider.size;
    List<Vector3> list = new();
    var signs = new List<int> { -1, 1 };
    signs.ForEach(signX => 
        signs.ForEach(signY => 
            signs.ForEach(signZ => {
                var vector = new Vector3(size.x * signX, size.y * signY, size.z * signZ);
                list.Add(boxCollider.transform.TransformPoint(boxCollider.center + vector * 0.5f));
            })));

    return list;
}
```