# How can I get a Box Collider's "corners" (vertices) positions?

Tags: unity, bounding-boxes

I attached a Box Collider to a object, which has not the center as its pivot. 
Now I need the 8 corner points.

Right now I can only get the points in a unrotated state. But whenever I rotate the Object (which rotates in the center of the boxCollider) - everything gets messed up, because the rotation alters the gameObject-Position.

EDIT2: Solution

```
public Vector3[] GetColliderVertexPositions (GameObject obj)  
{
    BoxCollider b = obj.GetComponent<BoxCollider>(); //retrieves the Box Collider of the GameObject called obj
    Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[8];
    vertices[0] = obj.transform.TransformPoint(b.center + new Vector3(-b.size.x, -b.size.y, -b.size.z) * 0.5f);
    vertices[1] = obj.transform.TransformPoint(b.center + new Vector3(b.size.x, -b.size.y, -b.size.z) * 0.5f);
    vertices[2] = obj.transform.TransformPoint(b.center + new Vector3(b.size.x, -b.size.y, b.size.z) * 0.5f);
    vertices[3] = obj.transform.TransformPoint(b.center + new Vector3(-b.size.x, -b.size.y, b.size.z) * 0.5f);
    vertices[4] = obj.transform.TransformPoint(b.center + new Vector3(-b.size.x, b.size.y, -b.size.z) * 0.5f);
    vertices[5] = obj.transform.TransformPoint(b.center + new Vector3(b.size.x, b.size.y, -b.size.z) * 0.5f);
    vertices[6] = obj.transform.TransformPoint(b.center + new Vector3(b.size.x, b.size.y, b.size.z) * 0.5f);
    vertices[7] = obj.transform.TransformPoint(b.center + new Vector3(-b.size.x, b.size.y, b.size.z) * 0.5f);

    return vertices;
}
```

Found that:

[Most efficient way to get the world position of the 8 vertexes of a Box Collider (C#)](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/109720/most-efficient-way-to-get-the-world-position-of-the-8-vertexes-of-a-box-collider)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Collider.bounds is an AABB (Axis-Aligned Bounding Box). An AABB is always parallel to the world axes. This figure that I just drew may help with the concept: [image]

Therefore, it does not have the corners of your box collider in local coordinates. Rotating it creates a weird situation.

If you are happy with AABB's, then use its coordinates without rotating. If you really need the corners of your box collider, you're going to have to use `BoxCollider.offset` and `BoxCollider.size` to calculate the local coordinates of the corners and then do `Transform.TransformPoint()` to get their world coordinates.

**Please note:** When trying to find coordinates within a `BoxCollider2D`, one must now use `BoxCollider2D.offset` instead of `BoxCollider2D.center`, as the latter is deprecated. The answer is updated to reflect this change.

Comment: thank you for your answer. 

BoxCollider.center and BoxCollider.size only gets me to the unrotated positions. 
I cant reach the Corners with them alone

Comment: did you try doing Vector3 rotatedCorner = transform.rotate * unrotatedCorner;?

Comment: Like I mentioned above, Transform.TransformPoint(unRotatedCorner) should give you the corners in world coordinates.

Comment: ok.. so: 
i tried "colVerts[i] = boxCol.transform.TransformPoint(colVerts[i]);"
          "colVerts[i] = transform.rotation * colVerts[i];"
None of them works.

Comment: Well, you must be doing something wrong, then.

Comment: thats  the reason im here

Comment: My answer does provide the answer to your question. Stack overflow is not "fix my code please", but we try. "It does not work" does not provide necessary details to provide an answer to "fix my code please".

Comment: indeed your answer would provide the answer to my question, if only the pivot of my Mesh would be centered. My Pivot is just way out of the center - which means: whenever i rotate my mesh, it rotates around the center of the BoxCollider. Also my BoxCollider is rotated after. And the transform.position is a whole different one, because the position rotate around the center of the BoxCollider.

Comment: Now: When with BoxCollider.center and BoxCollider.size i get the unrotated local coordinates, and with Transform.TransformPoint() i get the unrotated world coords. 
Vector3 colliderCenter = Vector3.Scale(transform.localScale, boxCol.center);
Gets me the real collider Center in World coordinates.

Comment: your first comment here tells me that you're not calculating the local corners right. would Vector3.Scale(transform.localScale, boxCol.center + Vector3(boxCol.size, 0, 0); give you one of the corners? give it to transform.TransformPoint() and you'll get the rotated world point.

Comment: oh, transform.TransformPoint() should also take care of scale for you. so, don't worry about scale. it should be something like transform.TransfromPoint(boxCol.center + Vector3(boxCol.size, 0, 0));

Comment: yes, witout rotation:

Vector3 colliderCenter = Vector3.Scale(transform.localScale, boxCol.center);


is always the center of the Box Collider, regardless of position and scale.

colliderCenter2 = transform.TransformPoint(transform.position?)
is not the collidercenter :S

Comment: why would you transform.TransformPoint(transform.position?) see my other comment above. transform.TransfromPoint(boxCol.center + Vector3(boxCol.size, 0, 0));

Comment: yay! i got it working... X.x